# Running firefox as a different user to sandbox

Tags: firefox

Given the fact that Linus Tech Tips got hacked yesterday (https://youtu.be/yGXaAWbzl5A), I'm pretty scared if some virus infects my Linux system and uploads the browser directories.

So I wanted to setup Firefox as a different user so that even if my system is compromised, the virus might not be able to steal data from the other user.

So I created a user called `firefox` (or something random). Copied the .mozilla/ to the user's directory. I changed the ownership recursively to `firefox:firefox`.

I modified the /bin/firefox-developer-edition to run `/opt/firefox-developer-edition/firefox` as the `firefox` user.

Now running firefox actually runs firefox as the other user. Great!

Everything works, but with few drawbacks:

Problems:

1. I now need to run `xhost +` every time I want to launch firefox. That's annoying but can be automated once system boots.
2. The most annoying problem is that whenever now I click a link on other apps like `discord` or telegram, the browser says

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile.

[image]

In other words, I'm only allowed to use one firefox process.

3. Notifications changed the way they look! They don't have the buttons like what I had in the past under XFCE.
4. Just discovered that sound doesn't work either with pipewire :(

Is there any way I can solve this issue? I want to make sure I can spawn as many firefox I want as the `firefox` user without having the above issues?

Comment: Why not run it in VM? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015334/how-could-a-virtual-machine-in-ubuntu-be-more-secure

Comment: Probably VM will use a tonne of more resources than just using it as a user

Comment: @SouravGoswami - If there is malware installed on the system, it’s pretty trivial, to access another users files. Linus fell victim to a session hijacking, so your approach won’t prevent that from happening.  Honestly not even, not keep sessions to services would prevent that, since the malware that hijacked Linus copied that active session at the time.